# Why does this block throw an error?

Tags: c#

"Not all code paths return a value"

```
 public BallData GetBall(String Name)
    { 
        //Check each item in the list for the name.
        foreach (BallData Item in _BallList)
        {
            //If the name matches, return the item to the caller and exit the loop.
            if (Item.Name == Name)
            {
                return Item;
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, throw an exception to indicate that the ball wasn't found.
                throw new KeyNotFoundException("The ball name doesn't exist.");
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you realize this will only look at the first item in `_BallList` before returning/throwing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
 foreach (BallData Item in _BallList)
 {
            //If the name matches, return the item to the caller and exit the loop.
            if (Item.Name == Name)
            {
                return Item;
            }

  }
  throw new KeyNotFoundException("The ball name doesn't exist.");
```

Comment: Same as the question's code, if `_BallList` is empty, the loop won' even happen.

Comment: @DidierGhys : It's not the same!

Comment: @DidierGhys which is why you throw "couldn't find it" only at the very end. why are people downvoting this?

Comment: @Mithrandir : That comment was added before you edited the post to remove the error.

Comment: Indeed, the throw was inside the loop when I commented.

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies. I'm working through a C# book and missed the placement.

Answer (score 3):

If `_BallList` is empty, you'll never get into the loop and thus the method does not return anything

Answer (score 1):

If _BallList is empty then nothing is returned.